# string inside php inside html inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i've searched on the site but i could find nothing that could help me.
I have a javascript code inside html inside php, i would like to know how i can put a string inside the javascript code with "breaking" the href with double quotes. Here is the code i have:

```
        return '<li class="slide_li" onmouseover="gmarkers['+marker_num+'].setIcon(getMarkerImage("grey", price, cur));" onmouseout="gmarkers['+marker_num+'].setIcon(gicons.blue)">'+details+'</li>';
```

The "grey" value breaks the href, i tried different ways like:
'grey', \'grey\', \"grey\" ecc.. but none of this worked for me. Any help is really appreciated. Thanx!

Comment: Try it like this \''grey'\' (note, they're all single quotes ')

Comment: This is not difficulf for you to solve yourself, expend 2 minutes effort on this and you will solve it.  I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I tried different ways, i'm stuck from a few hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such pain in the future, I am suggesting you my way of doing things in such scenarios.

Since you are already using jQuery library, why not to use its way of handling events:

```
$('li.slide_li').on({ 
            mouseover: function(e){


            },
            mouseoutleave:function(e){

        });
```

instead of using  inline javascript. This  will make you away from dealing with quotes. Additionnaly, by seperating the concerns this way, you  make your php return only markup.

About additional variables (like the variable containing 'grey'), I suggest you use data attributes, something like:

`return '<li class="slide_li" data-color='grey'></li>`

in javascript:

```
var color= $('li.slide_li').data(color);
// use color variable in code inside mouseover and mouseout
```

I am not telling here that the other answers are not adressing your current problem, I am only sharing a way I was told in the past it is a better way.

Comment: +1 escaping is annoying and doubly-escaping (here, into JavaScript and then into HTML) is very hard to get right. Avoid the problem by using objects and functions in preference to hacked-together markup strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `javascript` variable with additional `single quote` and then you need to used `backslash` like below:

```
return '<li class="slide_li" onmouseover="gmarkers[\''+marker_num+'\'].setIcon(getMarkerImage("grey", price, cur));" onmouseout="gmarkers[\''+marker_num+'\'].setIcon(gicons.blue)">'+details+'</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this `&quot;grey&quot;`
and it works!

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the variable outside of the javascript first:

```
    var variable="grey"

     return '<li class="slide_li" onmouseover="gmarkers['+marker_num+']
     .setIcon(getMarkerImage(variable, price, cur));" onmouseout="gmarkers['+marker_num+']
     .setIcon(gicons.blue)">'+details+'</li>'
```

;